# Inserting into a single table from multiple table

Tags: hadoop, hive, bigdata

I have defined multiple aliases in my query and I want to write the result of each alias into table `tab_1`. But when I run the following query I get error

> missing EOF at 'INSERT' near 'tab_1'

Have I written it correctly? Can someone verify the syntax or tell me how to write it? Please verify that I have put commas at right place. Appreciate for the help.

```
func_1 as
( .....),

func_2 as
(.....),

func_3 as
(....),


INSERT INTO TABLE tab_1 select * from func_1,

INSERT INTO TABLE tab_1 select * from func_2,

INSERT INTO TABLE tab_1 select * from func_3;
```

Comment: semi-colons, not commas: `INSERT INTO TABLE tab_1 select * from func_1;`

Comment: The answer you received below Nikki seems to be useful. Would you respond to the author please, and/or accept it, by clicking on the adjacent green tick symbol?

Answer (score 0):

Use this template:

```
with  
func_1 as ( .....),
func_2 as (.....),
func_3 as (....)
INSERT INTO TABLE tab_1 
select * from func_1
   union all  
select * from func_2  
   union all 
select * from func_3;
```

Subqueries in `union all` will be executed in parallel.

Checked explain plan on this sentence, it seems to work ok:

```
with func_1 as
( select * from default.dual),
func_2 as
(select * from default.dual)
insert into table default.dual
select * from func_1
union all 
select * from func_2
```